Automated inverse relationship inference/creation
Is there a solution to set relationships automatically? I am using Protégé 5.6.2.
Let's assume I created a class A, a class B and a relationship R. And I assereted that A--R->B. I also set the domain and range of R to be respectively A and B. Then I created invR as the inverse of R.
Inference 1 (DL Query) - At this point, the reasoner is able to infer that B is a superclass of invR some A.
Now I create the subclasses (and not instances) A1 and B1 for the classes respectively A and B. I set the relationship R between A1 and B1 (A1--R->B1), and bewteen A2 and B2 (A2--R->B2). Now I understand that the inference 1 (DL Query), this time applied to B1 and A1 does not hold. But that is what I want to obtain.
I tried SWRL rules but I they seem to apply only to instances, I can't set them up at a class level, correct me if I am wrong. In fact, I want either:
B1 to be a superclass of invR some A. or,
have directly B1--invR->A1 created in my ontology
I could of course create the relationship myself, but it is exactly what I want to avoid. In fact, my ontology will have hundreds of subclasses for the A and B class.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
